# Is it possible to extract the names of coefficients from $terms?

Tags: r

I have a test linear model:

```
set.seed(93874)
test_x <- rnorm(1000)
test_y <- rnorm(1000) + test_x
model  <- lm(test_y ~ test_x)
```

with the coefficients "intercept" and "test_x":

```
model$coefficients
(Intercept)      test_x 
 0.04047742  0.98198305
```

Using the command `model$terms` gives quite a bit of data

```
 > model$terms        
    test_y ~ test_x
        attr(,"variables")
        list(test_y, test_x)
        attr(,"factors")
               test_x
        test_y      0
        test_x      1
        attr(,"term.labels")
        [1] "test_x"
        attr(,"order")
        [1] 1
        attr(,"intercept")
        [1] 1
        attr(,"response")
        [1] 1
        attr(,".Environment")
        <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
        attr(,"predvars")
        list(test_y, test_x)
        attr(,"dataClasses")
           test_y    test_x 
        "numeric" "numeric"
```

from which I feel that I should be able to pull the names of the coefficients and use as row names in a matrix similar to the one generated by

```
 rows <- c("test_x")
     cols <- c("Value")
    matrix_test <- matrix(c(1), nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(rows, cols))
   > matrix_test 
          Value
    test_x     1
```

Is there a way to do this with a package or a command/function? I do not want to explicitly name the rows as doing so will make adding and removing variables in my actual program extremely cumbersome.

Comment: Do you want `names(model$coefficients)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes! That works perfectly. If you put that as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
names(model$coefficients)
[1] "(Intercept)" "test_x"
```

Or equivalently

```
> names(coef(model))
[1] "(Intercept)" "test_x"
```